# How to pay to Ubuntu by Master Card

Tags: canonical

In my country IRAQ, there's just Master Card available to pay. So its possible to pay with it to  Ubuntu or the lonely way is by Paypal.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

your Question can be successfully answered at : pay-support@canonical.com

mail them your issue.They will reply ASAP.

**Edit:** Got some reliable information : https://one.ubuntu.com/terms/#fees-and-payment

> If you purchase content or applications from us, payment for content
>   or applications is due at the time you purchase the content or
>   application. You will be asked to enter your credit card number and we
>   will charge your credit card at the time of purchase. Fees are charged
>   in the currency in which you make your purchase.
>
> Payment for services is handled for Canonical by a third party and
>   your credit card statement may identify Ubuntu One paid subscriptions
>   as “Canonical” or “PayPal”. All fees and paid accounts are
>   non-refundable. You are responsible for any foreign transaction fees
>   incurred by your bank.

Bottom line: If you have any credit card then you can do purchase & that's completely doesn't matter what Card it is.

Hope that helps.